# I have a D-visa in Poland. I stay in another Schengen country for almost 3 months. How long can I stay in other Schengen countries now?

Tags: visas, schengen, long-stay-visas

I have an activated D-visa from Poland which is valid from 1 Oct 2018.

Almost immediately before my D-visa's activation, I stayed in another Schengen country for close to 3 months with a C Schengen visa.

I understand that with a D-visa I can go to other Schengen countries under the 90/180 day rules. So my question now is - can I still do that? or I have to wait for another 3 months because of my previous travel under my C-visa?

Answer (score 3):

The rules are:

- You cannot stay longer than 90 out of 180 days in Schengen on any combination of visas.
- With a national D visa, time spent **in that country** does not count against the limit.

So you have at most a few days in other Schengen countries left.

Comment: And  the count is per person, not per visa or per passport.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question and got this from a Schengen consulate: 
"Indeed the 90/180 rule in the SHORT STAY VISA, is independent from the stay allowed in the VISA D (90/180 days)  in other Schengen country than the one which issued the visa D."

Indeed a Danish official website shows sth similar: 
"“Residence not included in the 90 day period

If you have stayed in Denmark … on the basis of a long-stay visa limited to another Schengen country (D-visa) this stay is not included in the maximum of 90 days in any 180-day period that you are allowed to stay in Denmark on a visa or as a visa-free.”